# Get value from closed worksheet using cell value as name

Tags: vba, path, vlookup

I have now searched this (and other websites) for a few days and I give up trying on my own.
My code does not want to give me values:

> Error 1004 unable to get the Vlookup property of the
>   WorksheetFunction class.

I don't want to open the other workbook to get the values, because I am making this sheet for others and they will basically freak out if something just pops up.

The code is as follows:

```
    Sub CashHoldings()  
    Dim RapportBok As Workbook  
    Dim RapportArk As Worksheet  
    Dim TradeFile As Worksheet  

    Set RapportBok = Workbooks("Rapport kunder")
    Set RapportArk = RapportBok.Sheets(1)
    Set TradeFile = Workbooks("Trade File Master 1").Sheets("Trade file")


    Dim wbPath As String, wbName As String
    Dim wsName As String, cellRef As String
    Dim Ret As String
    Dim cash As Long


    'wbPath = "F:\Oppgjør\Dagens trades\Dagen cash\"
    wbPath = "F:\Oppgjør\Dagens trades\Dagen cash\"

    wbName = RapportArk.Range("I2") & ".xlsx"
    wsName = "Kontantbeholdning Makro"
    cellRef = "L:N"

    Ret = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
          wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True)

     MsgBox Ret

    cash = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RapportArk.Range("C2"), Ret, 2, 
    False)

    End Sub
```

I get the correct name under Ret i.e. : `'F:\Oppgjør\Dagens trades\Dagens cash\[26.04.2017.xlsx]\Kontantbeholdning Makro'!$L:$N`

What am I missing??

Thank you in advance :)
Mille

Comment: The best way to do this would be to just open the workbook, and disable screenupdating. I work with suspicious users as well, but if you warn them in advance they generally don't mind it. Also, in the case of your code, when you are setting variables like `RapportBok = Workbooks("Rapport kunder")` is this workbook already open? If not (as far as I know) you will get an issue here since the workbook wont be within the workbook collection.

Comment: Hi, the Workooks("Rapport Kunder") is the book they will be working in so this is open. I don't want them to touch anything else than the three cell available to them (I2 and C2) so i hope to not have to open the book. could you though show me how to open and the close once the value is added?.. is it that diffcult to retreive the value with it closed? Thank you :)

Comment: To open just do `Workbooks.Open(filepath)' and I would recommend doing it something like `Set TargetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(filepath)`. To close once it is set to a variable just do `TargetWorkbook.Close(False)`. I am not certain how difficult it is to do it with the workbook closed given that it likely is slower, and relies on `Application.WorksheetFunction`. I strongly prefer doing it programmatically without relying on the sheets or workbooks. If I can retrieve the value by directly referencing the sheet I do.

Comment: thank you. i tried that now and it says "Sorry we couln't find 'F:\Oppgjør\Dagens trades\Dagens cash[26.04.2017.xlsx]\Kontantbeholdning Makro'!$L:$N.xlsx .. where is the extra last xlsx coming from? is it something in my macro that adds it again, not just in wbName? I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Dont do `Workbook.Open` on the full cell address. Just do `Workbook.Open` on the filepath. For example `Workbooks.Open("F:\Oppgjør\Dagens trades\Dagens cash.xlsx")`

Comment: hi, i treid that, but not working - it can't find the workbook. the wbName is the workbook. but I feel like giving up :p thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: Try `debug.print(wbName)` to ensure that the name is correct. If it is, try `ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink(wbName)` to see if that works.